# Tool for reading h.264 video files statistics

Tags: video, encoding, video-streaming, h.264, video-encoding

I am working on a project which requires me to play around with the h.264 encoder and come up with an optimal encoder settings for a particular bandwidth. Now I can change the #2-#4 below to try and achieve the desired bitrate, but I need a reliable tool which can play the recorded video and show me all values of the below parameters.

1. bitrate
2. Frame rate
3. GOP length (how frequently are key frames sent)
4. Resolution.

I have been using VLC player but don't think its reliable as I did not see the framerate updated when I changed it in my video. I also tried H264Visa and it seems a nice tool but the values are not so readily available.

Can anyone tell me what tool is the best for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GSpot is the tool, since a long time !

http://www.divx-digest.com/software/gspot.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Aby. GSpot tool solves most of the things that I wanted. However, it does not support the GOP structure for the H.264 and can't tell me the interval of key frames (GOP length).